# Measuring variability of log in hours

Tags: variance, mean, population

I'm working on measuring the usage patterns of an app for a population of users. I want to find out if they usually log in at the same hours or if their usage times vary a lot. The variance of the logging hours (e.g. 6pm, 7pm, etc...) would allow me to measure it for one user. But I want to measure this for several users. I'm not sure if calculating the mean of all the variances would be a valid approach. The lower the number is the less "variable" the logging hours are. Would this be a valid approach?

Comment: It might be better to first make some visual summaries of your data. In any case, the variance is not a useful summary for non-symmetric distributions.

Comment: I see. Which other options are there?